# Return the first result from csv file via PHP

Tags: php, csv

I have been looking and testing for a week with no luck. 
I want to seach the csv file for a location with the following php file:

```
<?php
$csv = fopen("file.csv", "r");
$row = fgetcsv($csv);
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
  $result = $key;
}
while ($row = fgetcsv($csv)) {
    if(in_array($result, $row)) {
        echo json_encode($row);
    }
}
?>
```

This works for one portion that I need it to. I have a second section which needs to do the same, except return ONLY the first result from the csv, but is instead returning multiple rows for all locations that it matches and I have tried removing the while loop

Comment: Use a "if" with a "break" https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Comment: Thank you Fellipe - this worked for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Fellipe commented above, you can break out of the loop in a few ways, easiest is simple `break;` statement

For example:

```
<?php
$csv = fopen("file.csv", "r");
$row = fgetcsv($csv);
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
  $result = $key;
}
while ($row = fgetcsv($csv)) {
    if(in_array($result, $row)) {
        echo json_encode($row);
        break; // exit while() loop
    }
}
?>
```

Also read the doco if your nesting loops (loops within loops). You then just pass in an int matching how many levels to 'break', ie: `break 2;`

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

> **break** (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)
>
> break ends execution of the current for, foreach, while, do-while or
>   switch structure.
>
> break accepts an optional numeric argument which tells it how many
>   nested enclosing structures are to be broken out of. The default value
>   is 1, only the immediate enclosing structure is broken out of.